# Does initiating Google account recovery immediately log you out of logged-in Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I plan to initiate Google account recovery, but I'm still logged in to Gmail on my older model iPad and my iPhone. Will initiating account recovery immediately log me out of Gmail on my iPad and iPhone and render those inaccessible until my account is successfully recovered? Or will that only happen once I successfully "recover" my account and change my password?

(The iPhone/iPad aren't successfully receiving 2FA codes, but that's probably because they're running pretty old iOS software. Somehow Google let me put my own email as the backup/recovery email address and I can't update that email address without going through the unsuccessful 2FA and I can't log in to my Google account on a newer model laptop without also going through the unsuccessful 2FA.)

Answer (score 0):

When you initiate account recovery, you will be logged out of all devices as a precautionary measure in case of a compromised account. This is done for security reasons.

Bear in mind that 2FA (Two Factor Authorization) is different from 2SV (2-Step Verification), where you get OTPs via SMS through your carrier/telecom operator.

If you're using an app for 2FA like Authy, LastPass or Google Authenticator, then consider shifting your accounts/tokens to another device.

Do you have any other alternate ways of getting into your account? and do you have any Backup Codes for the Google account in question? If so, use one of the backup codes to login on the desktop website, disable your 2FA temporarily, enable it again, this time with a new device and alternate phone number that works.

If you want to keep the Gmail accounts on your iPhone/iPad simply login again with your new password and 2FA token from the newer/alternate phone. This should hopefully solve the 2FA login issue.